# Interchange of partial derivative and limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Consider the following expression:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial m} \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \gamma(T,m)$$
where $\gamma$ is a function of $T$ and $m$.

My question is just: **can I permute the partial derivative and the limit operators**? I suppose that I can, given that the concerned variable is different for each operator but I still need a confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: No, you can't. Consider 
$$ \gamma(T, m) = \frac 1T \sin(T^2 m) $$
Then $\lim_T \gamma(T, m) = 0$, hence $\partial_m \lim_T \gamma(T, m) = 0$. But $\partial_m \gamma(T,m) = T\sin(T^2m)$ and $\lim_T \partial_m \gamma(T,m)$ does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the counter example. I think there exists a theorem indicating the required conditions to do this inversion but I did not manage to find a reliable source. Any idea ?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I add an answer to that question as a precision, since it is a question I also struggle with. Perhaps this answer will help other people.

Commuting derivative and limit is the same as commutativity of two limits.
Here, you can read a little about it :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interchange_of_limiting_operations

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit