# Exchange of differentiation and limit on a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, partial-derivative

For a differentiable function $f(x,y)$, is the following true,$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial \lim_{x\to 0} f(x,y)}{\partial y}$$ on a closed interval $y\in[0,\bar{y}]$? If not, when is it true? Similar question seems to have been asked, e.g.,[Interchange of partial derivative and limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424520). But no answer has been provided.

Comment: While I have voted to close this question for lack of context, it appears to have already been answered on MSE:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424520

Comment: You can try [Moore-Osgood theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Sufficient_condition)